# Geofencing Extension API - Uploading a New Layer

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to use Postman for upload a WKT layer by the cURL code below.

```
curl -X POST 
  'https://gfe.cit.api.here.com/2/layers/upload.json?layer_id=123&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}' 
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' 
  -F 'zipfile=@C:\xampp\htdocs\here\southern.wkt.zip'`
```

but the response message is

```
{"issues":[{"message":"Multipart should contain exactly one part"}],"error_id":"2e1e3994-69d6-43bb-8224-2a869b5255ae","response_code":"400 Bad Request"}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your WKT file doesn't contain additional **indentation(spaces)** avoid giving spaces and instead use equal **tabs** and give proper column names

refer [this](https://michalzalecki.com/implementing-geofencing-with-here/)